# Rayleigh quotient with multiple roots for one eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I wrote a python script which calculates the Rayleigh quotient with gradient descent line search.  This is just the original gradient descent as described by Nocedal et al etc. and I use the Armjio condition to check for sufficient decrease.

The code works fine for normal matrices.  I checked the min eigenvalue I get with those calculated from numpy.linalg.eigh(A) and they are all matching closely.

However, if I have a matrix that **has many eigenvalues that are 0, but each eigenvalue has a different eigenvector,** I have trouble converging to any of these eigenvectors.  I get other vectors that get my Rayleigh quotient down to 0, but they do not match what I get from numpy.linalg.eigh(A).
(but I can converge to eigenvector that corresponds to the max eigvalue which is not 0).

I need help in how to converge to the eigenvector when my eigenvalue is 0.

However, ultimately, I want to **skip all these 0 eigenvalues** and get the first eigenvector for the eigenvalue that is NOT 0.  If anyone can guide me to such an algorithm that would be fine as well!

Comment: What do you mean by the eigenvalues having different eigenvectors?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft I mean different eigenvectors all have the eigenvalue 0...I think this is called "degenerate eigenvalue"?

Comment: You can never get just a single eigenvector with a given eigenvalue unless you work over the field of 2 elements.